# View Not Found laravel 5.5

Tags: laravel-5, php7

Estoy utilizando un servicio host Apache/2.4.25 (Debian) y al ingresar a la vista admin me tira esto.
The requested URL /admin/boton_panico was not found on this server.

en web.php tengo así

```
Route::get('admin', "PaginasController@admin_monitoreo");

Route::get('/', "PaginasController@home");

Route::get('/index', "PaginasController@index");

Route::get('admin.boton_panico', "PaginasController@admin_panico");
```

y cree un controlador de paginas

```
    class PaginasController extends Controller
    {
        public function index(){
            return view ("welcome");
        }

        public function home(){
            return view ("home");
        }

        public function admin_monitoreo(){
            return view ("admin.admin");
        }

        public function admin_panico(){
        return view ("admin.boton_de_panico");
    }

    }
```

no se si es un error en mi configuración de las vistas? o un error de tipeo..

Comment: En el archivo de rutas no veo ninguna que sea: `admin/boton_panico`. No te dice que no encuentre una vista, te pone que no existe la url.

Comment: perdon ahi lo coloco

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quizá el error esté en ese punto `admin.boton_panico`

Prueba así:

```
Route::get('admin/boton_panico', "PaginasController@admin_panico");
```

El punto se utiliza para poner la ruta de las vistas desde el controlador; en las rutas se usa la barra.

Comment: en desarrollo funciona bien todas mis vistas, pero en produccion no, ahora acabo de ver de este post en stack-us [stackoverflow.com/questions/28242495/… y lo solucione... Faltaba conceder permisos desde el servidor, lo hice gracias a esto `<Directory /var/www/> Options Indexes FollowSymLinks AllowOverride All Require all granted </Directory>` cambiando desde esta direccion en apache `sudo nano /etc/apache2/apache2.conf`